# Flutter Server driven UI

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, dart-pub

- I am working on an ecommerce app where in home screen all widgets are to be set according to response which we get from the server.
- Now issue is whenever we got same type of widget multiple time means for e.g. we got advertise section two times,now we have to load advertise section multiple time and we have to call different api for both section,api is calling two times and its give also different response but when it time to display those data to UI,it takes data from which api is called last for both my instances.
- I am using bloc,dio.
- Can anybody tell the right solution for doing same ?
- Code of map widgets

```
mapWidgets(List<Datum> serverUi,
      HomeBodyDataState state,) {
    for (var element in serverUi) {
      String widgetType = element.keywords;
      serverWidgets.add(
        toWidget(element, widgetType, state),
      );
    }
    return serverWidgets;
  }

  Widget toWidget(Datum element,
      String widgetType,
      HomeBodyDataState state,) {
    switch (widgetType) {
      case AppStrings.advertiseSectionIdentifier:
        return Advertise(
          imagesList: state.advertiseSectionData.fold(
                () => null,
                (a) =>
                a.fold(
                      (l) => null,
                      (r) =>
                      r.value.fold(
                            (l) => null,
                            (r) => r,
                      ),
                ),
          ),
        );
      case AppStrings.sliderSectionIdentifier:
```

- Code of function which call api

```
    Future<Either<ValueFailures, HeaderImagesList>> getAdvertiseData({
        required String endPoint,
      }) async {
        log('api called : ${endPoint}');
        try {
          final response = await _dio.get(
            AppStrings.baseUrl + endPoint,
          );
          final result = response.data;
          log('api called : ${result.toString()}');
          return right(
            AdvertiseResponseModel.fromJson(result).toDomain(),
          );
        } on DioError catch (error) {
          return left(
            ValueFailures.serverError(
              failedValue: error.error.toString(),
            ),
          );
        }
      }
```

- In my point of view my values being overriden over times

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is very simple just store your API response in a local variable and user it when ever you need it then reset it after using

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).